# Return de Struct em C

Tags: c, struct, funções

Ola, Estou tentando retornar um struct de uma funcao quando ela for chamada no main. Eu fiz a funcao toda e definir no fim dois elementos que sao calculados na funcao:

```
int mult[100];
char** elemfim = (char**)malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));
```

Quero colocar esses dois em uma struct pra dar return para o main.

Entao defini no inicio do programa assim:

```
struct elementodos{
    int multidor[100];
    char** cadaum;
};
elementodos interpretar(char* element);
```

porem ele gera um errp quando eu defino a minha funcao, na parte:

```
elementodos interpretar(char* element);
```

Eu nao deveria definir minha funcao assim? para que eu consiga colocar um return de struct?

Comment: Você esqueceu de dizer _qual_ erro ele gera.

Comment: Tente assim: `struct elementodos interpretar(char* element);`

Comment: Obrigado Paulo Imon, era isso mesmo essa primeira parte pelo menos.

Comment: Opa! Mas no caso essa é só a assinatura da sua função, você vai ter que mudar na função também.

Comment: Mudei la tambem e funcionou, coloca como resposta para eu aceitar. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Pronto! Valeu! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso, essa é a assinatura da sua função.

Coloque assim nela:

`struct elementodos interpretar(char* element);`

E na sua função:

`struct elementodos interpretar(char* element) { ... }`

Você também pode utilizar o `typedef` para facilitar a construção do seu código.

Ex.:

```
struct elementodos{
    int multidor[100];
    char** cadaum;
};

typedef struct elementodos elem;
```

E então, você poderá utilizar assim:

`elem interpretar(char* element);` e 
`elem interpretar(char* element) { ... }`